# Re-opening a specific application in administrator priviledge

Tags: c#, windows-7, administrator, admin-rights

I would like to know if i can reopen an application with administrator privilege. For instance I have written a program which has to run Microsoft Outlook in admin mode. If i have opened Outlook with non-admin privilege then it gives me an error saying "Outlook not opened with administrator privilege". So if outlook is already opened then how do i reopen it with admin privilege.

Comment: Which version of windows? Which programming/scripting languges?

Comment: Windows 7. I am developing it in C#